# Microsoft Enterprise Library 3.1 - Validation - Message From resx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation, enterprise-library

I am trying to use the Enterprise Library 3.1 Validation Block for validating my objects in a new project. This application is to be multi-lingual and as such need to be able to put my error messages into resx files. How would you go about doing this? Would you use the config section or Attributes on the objects themselves and how do you specify the resx file to use?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Message Template Tokens**.
Take a look at the following link:

- [Validation Application Block Message Template Tokens and Resource Files](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/ValidationApplicationBlockMessageTemplateTokensResourceFiles.aspx)

You will find more in Enterprise Library documentation.